# JodaTime, instantiating a class

Tags: java, jodatime

I've a question which is very confusing to me. First i will tell what i know about instantiating an object from a specific class..

1. We create an instance ( or object ) of a class, by declaring a type ( may also be an Interface type ), a reference name ( variable ) and on the other side of equal operator we use keyword **new** to reserve memory for a specific type of object. We finish a statement with, a constructor call ( cant be interface, since interface cannot be instantiated )
2. Some classes have constructor, declared as **private**. That means we can't use constructor call to create a new object.
3. As alternative some classes "allow" instantiating an object via public or static methods, for example Calendar class. We get an instance of this class like this:

*Calendar variableRepresentingAnInstanceOrObject = Calendar.getInstance();*

(if something is wrong above, you can correct me )

Ok now i have a question, since i'm java begginer i'm a little confused with some classes in JodaTime libary. 
There are some classes called [Minutes](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/index.html) or [Hours](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Hours.html) etc. I already read documentation for those classes but i can't understand how to insantiate them. I'cant use keyword **new** since constructor is private ( eclipse is telling me that constructor is not visible). In declaration for minutes ( but not for hours ), says: *The number of minutes is set in the constructor, and may be queried using getMinutes()*. They neither have public or static methods to use  ( like calendar class ), as far as i know.

Which constructor? How to even call it?

Did i missed something in documentation, or did i missed something when i was learning java? Can someone please explain this to me. I will really appriciate. Thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class provides a few factory methods, such as:

```
Minutes m = Minutes.minutes(5); // a period of 5 minutes
Minutes m = Minutes.minutesBetween(date1, date2);
```

Check the `static` methods in the javadoc that return a `Minutes` object, most of them are factory methods.

Comment: Oh okay i see and understand now. Thanks. But can you tell me what is variable "m" holding then in this example:

Minutes m = Minutes.minutes(5);
instance of class Minutes, and represents ..5 minutes ?

Comment: Yes - m is an instance of Minutes representing 5 minutes. Note that it is not necessarily a new instance of Minutes as Minutes objects might be cached (cf javadoc). But that does not really matter.

Answer (score 0):

`Minutes` has a static factory method [`minutes(int minutes)`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Minutes.html#minutes%28int%29), and `Hours` has [`Hours.hours(int hours)`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Hours.html#hours%28int%29).